# Does Active Record's first method sort by id?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When calling `User.last` it looks like Active Record sorts by `id`.

`User Load (1.4ms)   SELECT * FROM`users`ORDER BY users.id DESC LIMIT 1`

But when calling `User.first` it doesn't use an order clause.

`User Load (1.9ms)   SELECT * FROM`users`LIMIT 1`

So is this guaranteed to return the User with the lowest id?  It seems to in practice but I'm not sure if MySQL guarantees this.

Or do you have to do this: `User.first(:order => 'id')` which forces the order clause.

Edit: I guess this is really a MySQL question.  Is `SELECT * FROM`users`LIMIT 1` guaranteed to return the user with the lowest id?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what ActiveRecord does by default, but you can force a default order in your model using ActiveRecord's [default_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope) method:

```
default_scope :order => "id ASC"
```

or in Rails 3

```
default_scope order("id ASC")
```

Comment: but does AR force ordering by ID, by default mysql orders records by freshness ... or i'm wrong?

Comment: I can only assume that for default order for first, AR simply does nothing and leaves the ordering to the DB, which will in the case o MySQL orders by insert order, which happens to correspond to "id ASC". For last, this approach doesn't work, so AR uses "id DESC". But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

It will return the same result as

```
select * from users limit 1
```

so its up to your database how to order data. i.e. you have to add any of above mentioned order methods.